# Run two Spring endpoints at the same time

Tags: java, spring-boot, endpoint, spring-restcontroller

I have a Controller class with two endpoints:

```
@GetMapping("/refresh")
public String refresh() {
// does something
}

 @GetMapping("/watch")
    public String watch() {
    // does something
}
```

When I call the endpoint /watch I want to call the /refresh endpoint before (more precise I only make one call to the endpoint /watch but /refresh gets called before)

I tried to instantiate it like this:

```
 @GetMapping("/watch")
public String watch() {
refresh();
// does something
}
```

but it did not work has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you simply not call the implementing logic in watch() and then do something more in watch() if ou want?

Comment: you mean that I implement the logic from refresh in watch? If yes I tried it but it did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I would advise to just not doing that but if you must you can do something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/refresh");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Tho as Gurkirat has correctly pointed out in the comments, you should not do this and instead call the business logic of `/refresh` in `/watch`